# How to play GIF's using turtle module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want the GIF to play in the turtle screen. But it is showing only the still image. Please fix this,  Any help will be appreciated...

**Here is my code:**

```
import turtle
import os

# resources :
bgpic = r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\xBDT7.gif"


win = turtle.Screen()
win.addshape(bgpic)

sh = turtle.Turtle()
sh.shape(bgpic)


# Shuting the window down :
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the `turtle` documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html), I don't see anything that says animated gifs can be played within turtle. You are free to read the documentation yourself, but It appears that although to use an image as a shape or background in turtle, it needs to be a `.gif` file, you cannot actually playback animated gifs in turtle.

Comment: I know that turtle uses gif and .png images only & i have seen many youtube videos where their gif's are playing but mines are not... Is there anyway i can sort this problem out??

Comment: @Andrewwhiteman You sure you are not thinking about `Pyglet`? I've looked up "Playing GIF animation in python with turtle module", and only got a video titled "Pyglet Python Adding GIF Image And Animation".  And from my limited time working with `turtle` , I've never heard of being able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
# in order to use GIF as shape you have to register them first
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
from food import Food
from scoreboard import ScoreBoard
import time


screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgpic("background.gif")
screen.title("Snake Game")
screen.tracer(0)
screen.register_shape("apple.gif")
screen.register_shape("snake.gif")
screen.register_shape("snake_head.gif")
screen.register_shape("snake_head_right.gif")
screen.register_shape("snake_head_up.gif")
screen.register_shape("snake_head_down.gif")
```

you can find more detailed information at https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).