# Why can't I use a gif as a background with Turtle in Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I try to use a gif as a background for a game.
The games works fine but the background is stuck on the first frame of the gif.
I'm using Turtle library with Python.
Thank you :)

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(800, 600)
screen.bgpic('background.gif')
screen.update()
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126255/how-to-play-gifs-using-turtle-module-in-python) will help you, apparently you can't play animated gifs.

Comment: So it's impossible to use gifs with turtle, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly we cannot use gifs with Turtle.